# How to change the font size and zoom level in Spyder-Notebook and Spyder-Terminal?

Tags: spyder

I have started using Spyder-Notebook and Spyder-Terminal and like them both very much.  They both add great usability features that Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab do not provide all in a simple user interface.  I work on high-resolution screens and need to make the Spyder-Notebook documents and fonts larger, particularly when I am delivering training over Zoom.

With Spyder's iPython Console, the Ctrl_Shift+ or Ctrl_- shortcuts zoom in and out.

I have looked for Spyder-Notebook and Spyder-Terminal controls and options in the GUI and menus to try to change font size and zoom in on the notebook documents, but there are no zoom controls or Settings menu interface specifically to address this.

Are there Settings in a configuration text file (e.g., .yaml, .cfg, .ini) or somewhere else that allows me to change the zoom level and font sizes?  If so, where are the configurations located and how can they be changed?  Where is the documentation for the internals for Spyder-Notebook and Spyder-Terminal?

Any assistance with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can right-click in the notebook and click zoom in or zoom out. This is referenced here as well:  https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook/issues/174

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but it works.  It is a non-standard Jupyter Notebook or iPython GUI behavior.   Thank you for pulling it out of the Github Issues page for the Spyder-Terminal plugin !!